# Вылетает окно при нажатии на кнопку PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Получаю ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'MyTest' object has no attribute 'btn'

как исправить?

Код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
import sys


class MyTest(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Amin')
        btn = QPushButton('Кнопка', self)
        btn.resize(100, 50)
        btn.move(100, 125)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.hello)

    def hello(self):
        self.btn.setText('Привет!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyTest()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: ну во-первых надо дебажить, чтобы узнать ошибку, а во-вторых здесь `btn = QPushButton('Кнопка', self)` вы объявляете не поле класса, а локальную переменную

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: сделайте объект `btn` атрибутом класса, т.е. `self.btn`

Answer (score 2):

Здесь

```py
btn = QPushButton('Кнопка', self)
```

вы объявляете локальную переменную, а не поле класса. Следовательно, когда вы пытаетесь получить поле с именем `btn` из другой функции,

```py
self.btn.setText('Привет!')
```

у вас возникает ошибка

Сделайте так:

```py
self.btn = QPushButton('Кнопка', self)
```